# Get a key value from a JSON asset in PHP

Tags: php, json, plugin-applenews

I'm using the Apple News plugin to try and display a tweet that's been added as a JSON asset in a matrix field. The JSON looks something like this

```
{
    "title": "https://twitter.com/TehseenLadha/status/1291773476877959169",
    "description": null,
    "url": "https://twitter.com/TehseenLadha/status/1291773476877959169",
    ...
}
```

According to the [Apple News Publisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/tweet) docs, all you need is the tweet's URL. I'm trying to get it by converting the JSON file to a string with `file_get_contents` and then using `json_decode`, but it's not working. This is what I have in MyNewsArticle.php:

```
case 'tweet':
  $asset = $block->tweet->one()->getUrl();
  $string = file_get_contents($asset);
  $jsonArr = json_decode($string, true);
  $tweetUrl = $jsonArr['url'];

  if ($tweetUrl) {
    $components[] = [
      'role' => 'tweet',
      'layout' => 'tweetLayout',
      'URL' => $tweetUrl,
    ];
  }
break;
```

It's grabbing the correct URL of the asset, but fails with `failed to open stream: Operation timed out` on the `$string = file_get_contents($asset);` line. Apparently this is something to do with IPv4 vs IPv6? I'm not certain how to get around it though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't Craft specific. Stack Overflow might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `$block->tweet->one()` returns an Asset element in your matrix block called `tweet`. I suggest that you use the `getContents()` method on Craft's Asset element type to retrieve the string content of the actual file. Your code block would look something like this:

```
case 'tweet':
  $tweetFileContent = $block->tweet->one()->getContents();
  $tweetJson = json_decode($tweetFileContent, true);
  $tweetUrl = $tweetJson['url'];

  if ($tweetUrl) {
    $components[] = [
      'role' => 'tweet',
      'layout' => 'tweetLayout',
      'URL' => $tweetUrl,
    ];
  }
break;
```

However, I would recommend extending your code as follows to address empty state and potential exception:

```
case 'tweet':
  if (empty($block->tweet)) {
    // return early or do something else
  }
  try {
    $tweetFileContent = $block->tweet->one()->getContents();
    $tweetJson = json_decode($tweetFileContent, true);
    $tweetUrl = $tweetJson['url'];

    if ($tweetUrl) {
      $components[] = [
        'role' => 'tweet',
        'layout' => 'tweetLayout',
        'URL' => $tweetUrl,
      ];
    }
  } catch ($e) {
    // getContents() throws 
    // InvalidConfigException if [[volumeId]] is missing or invalid,
    // AssetException if a stream could not be created
  }
break;
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks so much 